# how do i view messages and wall posts from deleted friends

Tags: facebook, find

how do i view messages and wall posts from deleted friends?   A friend has been involved in a crime and the criminal has deleted friendship. There was a lot of correspondence pertaining to this theft via messaging and wall posts. He is trying to locate these correspondences to show to authorities...
Please help.

Thank you.
Chris Helmerson

Comment: Try contacting Facebook.

Comment: You should try to contact Facebook directly for something like this.  They probably still have the information somewhere.  This isn't really a technical question so it doesn't belong on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to contact Facebook for that. That's not something we'll be able to help you with here as it's a restriction from Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook allows users download archive with personal information (including wallposts and messages). To download it you should go to Account Settings, at the bottom of page you will see "Download a copy of your Facebook data."

More information at [Facebook Help Center](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=116481065103985)